# Google Calendar API batch request PHP

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

i am trying to send a bunch of events via an Batch Request to Google Calendar.
But i cant figur out how to do. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/batch doesnt help me.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setUseBatch(true);
$batch = new Google_BatchRequest();

$uri = 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/batch';
$batchContent = file_get_contents('xxxxx/google-api-php-client/batch.xml');    

$batch->add($batchContent);
```

batch.xml contains 2 -items.
Thats all so far. But nothing happened.

I also have tried

```
$batch->execute()
```

But thats throws error without message.

***My question: How to send a Batch via PHP to Google Calendar ?***

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the latest version of Google APIs Client Library for PHP (Google Calendar v.3). I use batch operations for pushing instructor lessons to Google Calendar. Here is my example of code for you (multipleInsert function). Good luck!

```
<?php
require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/Google/Client.php');
require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/Google/Http/Batch.php');
require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/Google/Service/Calendar.php');

class My_google_calendar
{
  ...

  /** Add single Event for Student */
  function addEvent($lesson, $instructor, $return_request = false, $enable_attendees = false)
  {
    $calendar = $this->getGoogleCalendar(); // get calendar service variable

    $lesson_from = date(DATE_RFC3339, $lesson->from);
    $lesson_to = date(DATE_RFC3339, $lesson->from + $lesson->duration); 

    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
    $event->setSummary('Lesson with student: '$lesson->student_full_name);

    $start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($lesson_from); 
    $start->setTimeZone($this->getGoogleCalendarTimeZone());
    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($lesson_to);
    $end->setTimeZone($this->getGoogleCalendarTimeZone());
    $event->setEnd($end);
    $event->setColorId(4);

    $description = "...";
    $event->setDescription($description);

    if (isset($student->email) && $enable_attendees) {
      $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
      $attendee1->setResponseStatus('needsAction');
      $attendee1->setEmail($student->email);
      $attendees = array($attendee1);
      $event->setAttendees($attendees);
    }

    $createdEvent = $this->calendar->events->insert($this->calendar_id, $event, array('fields' => 'id'));
    return $return_request ? $createdEvent : $createdEvent->getId();
  }

  /** Push group of events to the Calendar */
  function multipleInsert ($lessons, $instructor)
  {
    $this->use_batch = true;
    $this->client->setUseBatch($this->use_batch);
    $batch = new Google_Http_Batch($this->client);
    $optParams = array('fields' => 'status,updates');

    foreach($lessons as $time => $lesson) {      
        $lesson = array_shift($group['lessons']);
        $req = $this->addEvent($lesson, $instructor, true);
        $batch->add($req, $time);
      }
    }
    $results = $batch->execute();

    return $results;
  }

}
```

Comment: This was a perfect example. Helped me out a ton, thanks @Natali!

Answer (score 1):

in the newer versions, you should use

```
$batch = $service->createBatch();
```

instead of

```
$batch = new Google_Http_Batch($this->client);
```

[reference](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/examples/batch.php)